# Windows cmd batch - set attribute of a file to an variable

Tags: batch-file

I have difficulties dealing with files with comma in filename in CMD batch script:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
if not exist "%~f1" (
    echo Usage: pdf-decrypt.bat [file-to-decrypt]
    goto :eof
)
echo "%~f1"
set ATTR=%~a1
set DIRATTR=%ATTR:~0,1%
if /I "%DIRATTR%"=="d" (
    echo %~f1 is a folder
) else (
    echo %~f1 is a file
)
```

Output:

```
λ pdf-decrypt.bat 201905_DOE,JOHN.pdf

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

if not exist "C:\Users\john.doe\Desktop\201905_DOE" (
echo Usage: pdf-decrypt.bat [file-to-decrypt]
 goto :eof
)
Usage: pdf-decrypt.bat [file-to-decrypt]
```

I have to quote them with `" "`.

Comment: The issue is not with your batch file itself, its with your input to it. You should be passing that input as `pdf-decrypt.bat "201905_DOE,JOHN.pdf"`, or preferably, `"pdf-decrypt.bat" "201905_DOE,JOHN.pdf"`. Please also note that if your end user is just inputting `"201905_DOE,JOHN.pdf"`, using `~f` expansion will not magically add the correct missing drive and path information, it will more than likely just add that of the current directory.

Comment: OK so I have to quote it. And when you say `~f` expansion adds current folder, I think yes and no; yes, when the file does not exist it add current path; but if it exists will expand to right full path.

Comment: Possibly I wasn't clear enough, If you have a file, lets say, `C:\Windows\write.exe`, and your current directory is `C:\Users\WesternGun\Desktop`, and `pdf-decrypt.bat` is located in that current directory, then enter `pdf-decrypt.bat write.exe`, `%~f1` will return `C:\Users\WesternGun\Desktop\write.exe`. Also if your batch file was located on your desktop, but your current directory was `C:\Users\WesternGun` and you input `Desktop\pdf-decrypt.bat write.exe`, `%~f1` would return `C:\Users\WesternGun\write.exe`. The point I'm making is that you are relying on the end user input being correct.

Comment: So the input file does exist, and the output is reporting the incorrect path. What I think you meant is that it adds it when the file does not exist in the current directory. Does your end user know for sure what the current directory is, when they provide input to your batch file? are they to rely perhaps on the prompt string telling them? how do they know that the current directroy isn't modified within the batch file to another one? i.e. `CD /D "C:\Users\WesternGun\Documents"`?

Comment: If the current directory path is being added, and your expectation is that the current directory should be assumed, or known by the end user, then there's no need to use `%~f1`, just `%~1` should be sufficient.

Comment: OK. I understand what you mean now, but the expansion part of `~f` is not the crucial part of my question. The real question, and what is important to me now, is that if I have to quote the filename to make CMD parse it if the name contains comma. I got your confirmation in the first comment, so that's it.

Comment: That's correct, I provided an immediate solution to your issue in my first sentences. The rest was an additional note, to inform you that you were using something you didn't need to use, and an explanation of why. Please don't discount advice, because it wasn't a solution to your reported issue. That is one of the purposes of the comment area, to help you to make modifications/improvements or expand your understanding.

Comment: BTW, its not just commas which will cause issues, the recommended advice is that you, or I suppose your end user, always doublequotes. _Hence the reason I showed you in my first comment, `"pdf-decrypt.bat" "201905_DOE,JOHN.pdf"`_. I should also mention that you could replace your first two lines with one, `SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion`.